# How to filter `objects` by it's value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-filters

In my angular controller, I would like to filter and assign some object with `true` value. i am trying to iterate using `angular.forEach` but i am getting all object as result instead of getting the truthy object.

here is my code :

```
$scope.splash.$promise.then(function (result) {

            $scope.allApps = result; //50 apps.
            // splashAppsHandler();

            $scope.splashApps = angular.forEach( $scope.allApps, function (app) {

                return app.projects.project.splash === true; //only 5 apps

            });

            console.log($scope.splashApps); //getting all 50 apps!?


        });
```

What is the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to store truthy objects with in an array or object. Currently you are not doing inside angular forEach.

```
$scope.truthyObjects = [];
$scope.splash.$promise.then(function (result) {

        $scope.allApps = result; //50 apps.
        // splashAppsHandler();

        $scope.splashApps = angular.forEach( $scope.allApps, function (app) {

            if(app.projects.project.splash === true) {
                 $scope.truthyObjects.push(app); // save truthy object
            }

        });

        console.log($scope.splashApps); //getting all 50 apps!?


    });
```

Comment: Yes, works. my question is in future the `$scope.truthyObjects` object modified, will the ` $scope.allApps` will update? else how to handle?

Comment: Do you need `$scope.allApps` to have only truthy objects ?

Comment: No, it should contain all apps, that's fine. from the allapps, i need some apps to high light in the page. now i taken some object to `trurythObjects`, when i made any change on `truthyObjects` will that updated to `allapps` too?

Comment: no it will not. what do you mean by "i need some apps to high light in the page" ?

Comment: which has the `splash==true` and from that(5), the first one should be in `h1` tag, rest 4 should be in `h2` tag.